# change href to onclick

Tags: php, wordpress

On wordpress, does anyone know how to programatically change link from:

```
<a href="some_url">click</a>
```

to:

```
<a onclick="window.open('some_url','_blank', 'location=no')">click</a>
```

so that all links created in the wordpress visual editor be opened via inappbrowser in a cordova app.

After googling around, below is the closest that i can get, but still doesn't work, the `'%link%'` variable doesn't change to the actual link url :

```
add_filter('the_content', 'changeToOnclick');
function changeToOnclick($content) {
    return preg_replace('/<a [^>]*>/', "<a onclick=\"window.open('%link%', '_blank', 'location=no')\">", $content);
}
```

any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do this using JavaScript? At least the `href` is still usable in the event of JavaScript being disabled.

Comment: sorry, i am a real newbie in coding, can you show me the javascript code? i'll try to use it in my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do exactly what you want is this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'changeToOnclick');
function changeToOnclick($content) {     
     return preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?)">/', '<a onclick="window.open(\'$1\', \'_blank\', \'location=no\');">',$content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to do search and replace using wp filter you can do this :

```
function change_submenu_class($menu) {
  $menu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="dropdown" /',$menu);
  return $menu;
    }
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu','change_submenu_class');
```

So just replace the parts of javascript with this and give it a try

Comment: but he need keeps the url, the other stuff need to be replaced, i post the correct way to do that

Comment: hmm I saw that, the problem is if he is using the add filter all the links will get replaced . better if he uses it in some div maybe !

Comment: Thanks Kisuke for the suggestion, but i do want all links to be replaced. i'll keep your solution as it is also useful for me :)